# mongodb User with subdocument vs document with UserId

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, meanjs

I am using meanjs and I would like to store some user data in a one to many relationship. My case is similar to the articles example but the articles will only ever be accessed through the user. I want the route to be something like

```
Users/:userId/articles
```

or

```
Users/me/articles
```

Question 1
Should I just stick with the articles model as it is or should I make articles a subdocument of user. e.g.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
    },
    displayName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your email'],
        match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: 'testing error message',
        required: 'Please fill in a username',
        trim: true
    },
    articles: [articleModel.schema],
    password: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyPassword, 'Password should be longer']
    },
    salt: {
        type: String
    },
    provider: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Provider is required'
    },
    providerData: {},
    additionalProvidersData: {},
    roles: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: ['user', 'store', 'admin']
        }],
        default: ['user']
    },
    updated: {
        type: Date
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    /* For reset password */
    resetPasswordToken: {
        type: String
    },
    resetPasswordExpires: {
        type: Date
    }
});
```

Question 2 if I make it a subdocument can I still use the $resource function or do I have to make custom functions?

Comment: Experts advise not to embed data that will continue to grow infinitely, as would be the case with a user's articles.

Comment: Thanks that makes it easier to code for me.

Comment: The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes. The maximum document size helps ensure that a single document cannot use excessive amount of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount of bandwidth. To store documents larger than the maximum size, MongoDB provides the GridFS API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes. The maximum document size helps ensure that a single document cannot use excessive amount of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount of bandwidth. To store documents larger than the maximum size, MongoDB provides the GridFS API.

Comment: So does that mean that I should go as separate documents instead of sub documents if the article sizes may grow to exceed 16MB?